# How to prove this set is Linearly Independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling to prove this:

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$, and let $\left\{0\right\}=V_0\subsetneq V_1 \subsetneq . . . \subsetneq V_n=V$ be subspaces of $V$. Then the set  $\left\{v_1, . . . ,v_n\right\}$ such that $v_i \in V_i\setminus V_{i-1}$ for every $1\leq i \leq n$ ,  is Linearly independent

First i tried to prove the case where $n=2$ and even struggled there.

Thanks for any help

Comment: But the base case is just $\{v_1\}$ where $v_1\neq 0$ because of the stated condition. That set is trivially linearly independent.

Comment: ye you're right, i was referring to the case where n=2

Comment: Technically, you haven't excluded $v_1 \neq 0$. I think you should exclude the condition $v_1\in V_1$ and just have $v_i \in V_i\setminus V_{i-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argue by contradiction, and suppose that they are linearly dependent. Then there exists some nonzero linear combination
$$a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n=0$$
where $(a_1, \dots , a_n) \neq (0, \dots ,0)$. Let $N= \max \{ i:a_i \neq 0 \}$. Then
$$a_1v_1 + \dots + a_Nv_N=0$$ with $a_N \neq 0$. Hence
$$v_N= -a_N^{-1}(a_1v_1 + \dots + a_{N-1}v_{N-1}) \in V_{N-1}$$
you got a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The inductive step

Let $\alpha_i\in\Bbb K$ for $1\le i\le k+1$ such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\alpha_i v_i=0\iff \alpha_{k+1} v_{k+1}=-\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i v_i\in V_k\cap V_{k+1}=V_k$$
and since $v_{k+1}\not\in V_k$ then $\alpha_{k+1}=0$ and then $\alpha_i=0$ for all other $i$ by inductive hypothesis.